# Need help on configuring password Policy

Tags: centos7, password-protection

would need some help in configuring password policy on CentOS 7. Currently I am tasked to implement these policies on server:

Passwords must be complex. Use the following types of characters:
(a) 1 uppercase letter as the first letter,
(b) 5 lowercase letters,
(c) 2 special character

I have manage to do the rest except for part (a). I have no idea on how to enforce first character of password to be an uppercase letter.

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: can you share how did you configure part b & c?

Comment: Edit /etc/security/pwquality.conf and set the complexity as per your requirement.